# Github Pages won't load local video I added

Tags: html, css, html5-video, github-pages

So I have an index.html file that applies a video stored in my computer to be full screened while other texts showing on top of it. But github pages seem not working: there's no video running in the background. Yet, it works as intended when I run it in Atom. Besides, I've already used git LFS to track the video and push it to my repo as you can see from the picture below:
[Picture showing my repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNPHs.png).

This is what the website look like locally.
[Website in local environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwE8R.jpg)

This is it on github pages: [Website hosted by github pages (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Udcu.jpg)

The repository link is: https://github.com/ecoist-ste/pw-version2/blob/master/index.html

And the link to the website hosted by github pages is:https://ecoist-ste.github.io/pw-version2/

Below is a part of index.html and style.css that makes the vide fullscreened.

```css
.v-header{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color:white;
}

.container{
  max-width: 960px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video{

  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="v-header container">
  <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
      <video src="background_video.mp4" autoplay muted loop>
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="header-overlay">
  <div class="header-content container">
    <h1 style="font-size:200px">...</h1>
    <p style="font-size:100px">...</p>
  <button onClick="document.getElementById('Start').scrollIntoView();" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" style="font-size:50px; color: pink; border-radius:60px">Learn More</button>

</div>

    

</header>
```

Comment: If it works locally and doesn't work when you upload it to a website then we won't be able to tell what the problem is just by looking at the code.

Comment: Do some [debugging](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Use the developer tools in  your browser. Look at the Console: Are any errors reported? Look at the Network tab: Is the HTTP request for the video made? Does it get a response? Is the status code right? Look at the Elements panel: Does the `<video>` appear? Does it have the right dimensions (e.g. maybe something is causing it to render with no pixels you can see)?

Comment: Hi Quentin, I just added pictures of the website in both cases. Also, I did what you suggested. Out of all questions you gave me, I noticed two: 1)Console: "Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform".  2) Network tab for the video says "The request has not response data available".

Comment: Oh and I'm not sure about the status code. It's green and has a value of 206 next to the color.

Comment: @Steve, see if my answer helps you. If still failing then tell us the repository link (if privacy is the issue, you can delete a comment with link later on, after we get chance for checking it)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your repository:

[image]

You need to use the `Download` link of the MP4 file.

To get the link:

1. You need to click the MP4 filename (takes you to the preview page)
2. You'll see a file Preview page where there's a `Download File` button in top-right of screen.
3. Right-click the button and choose "copy link".
   Or you can click button and then get address from browser bar when video plays.
4. The link is for using as `.src=` in your video Element.

eg:
https://github.com/XXX/XXX.github.io/raw/master/public/background_video.mp4

**edit:**

Set your video object up like this:

```
<video id="myBGvid" autoplay muted loop>
<source src="your_link_MP4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Check the edit, your video object is not setup correctly... Also  added an `Id` in case you need to later control by Javascript (_eg:_ adjust width/height, z-depth layer positioning, etc)

Comment: Where `your_link_MP4` is: [https://github.com/ecoist-ste/pw-version2/raw/master/background_video.mp4](https://github.com/ecoist-ste/pw-version2/raw/master/background_video.mp4)

Comment: I made these changes but it didn't work though. I found it elsewhere that said web browsers don't support mp4 file anymore but webM. Could that be a problem?

Comment: MP4 is the most supported format. The problem is having a 155 MB file as a background visual. Somehow your file was working yesterday but is now moved to their [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) which means that `background_video.mp4` is now a text file pointing to the storage location, but video tag cannot play text files....  **(1)** Does LFS mean anything to you (can your account see the real MP4 link somewhere in their options)?

Comment: Or else... **(2)** If possible re-upload a smaller file (resolution can be 1920x1080p) where file size is smaller than 30 or 20 MB. Use a video editor or a tool like FFmpeg to re-encode a smaller copy.... Settings can help keep same visual quality in a **really small file** so experiment. For me I expect to load 155 MB for an hour long file, not some seconds. I don't know how your file came out so big for what it does... PS: A background should be fast loading (eg a small file). Here 10 visits/refreshes on your site will cost the user 1.5 GB of data transfer (RIP if using paid mobile data)...

Comment: Haha poor mobile-data user. I finally worked it out by changing the video to a one with smaller size. Thank you so much for the patient help!